# Problem with theorem numbering

Tags: theorems

I want to write my homework in Tex

How can I write "**Theorem 18.**" using command: \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} .
It starts numbering my theorem automatically as **Theorem 1.**
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should earlier write `\setcounter{thm}{17}`. I am assuming, that you have an article-like class, not a book-like class.

Comment: But the next Theorem is 25, I want to numerate it manually. What is the suggestion.

Comment: @Pinky Then next you can write `\setcounter{thm}{24}`. As far as I understand, it is an excerpt from a manual as a part of your homework. A MWE (minimal working example) can help in understanding the problem.